# Angular 5 with ngx infinite scroll not fired

Tags: angular5, nginfinitescroll

i'm using ngx-infinite-scroll module with Angular 5. My browser is Chrome.

The `onScrollDown()` action is fired when i scroll down with the scrolling bar inside my div. To make it work, i need to give a height to my content and `[scrollWindow]` should be set to false:

**css**

```
 .search-results {
      height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

**template**

```
<div class="search-results"
         infinite-scroll
         [infiniteScrollDistance]="5"
         [infiniteScrollThrottle]="10"
          [scrollWindow]="false"
         (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
      <p *ngFor="let i of array">
        {{i}}
      </p>
    </div>
```

But when i set `[scrollWindow]` to true (which is the default setting), and remove the `search-results` class (no height set then), the onScrollDown() is never fired even when i scroll down with the default right bar of my browser. Any idea why the default windows scrolling doesnt trigger the onScollDown() action? Thanks

Comment: Right now the plugin has this issue,  it's a shame! (11/04/2018)

Answer (score 0):

I found that even though the documentation claims that windowScrolled default it's true if I don't set it explicitly to true the listened is not bound to the window scroll.